# Is it correct to say “things are looking up for my travel plans”

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, idioms, colloquialisms, idiom-meaning

Is it correct to say “things are looking up for my travel plans” to indicate that I am ready to start planning my travel after so many problems.

Comment: it may not be grammatical but it is pretty standard in the UK.

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything wrong grammatically, but I wouldn’t interpret it as meaning you can now start planning.  I’d think it meant you already had started planning but were running into problems in the planning process.  Afterall, you mention “your travel plans” which mean they already exist in some form.  If you had overcome problems that prevented you from starting your planning I might think, “Things are looking up me being able to make travel plans.”

Comment: Yes I did start planning but there were issues and so had to pause for a while. Now the issues have been resolved.

Comment: You'd probably want to say, instead, *Things are looking up for my proposed trip.*

Answer (score 1):

In fact, ***for** [person or situation with improved prospects]* is [by far the most common word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=things%20are%20looking%20up%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthings%20are%20looking%20up%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20as%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cthings%20are%20looking%20up%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20again%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthings%20are%20looking%20up%20as%3B%2Cc0) to follow idiomatic ***things are looking up***...

[image]

Presumably OP's doubts spring from the fact that *usually* the "subject" with "improved prospects" is a *person* (or at least, something "animate"). But that's like thinking there's something wrong with saying *X is bad for **my health*** rather than *...bad for **me***. Situations, plan, and other abstract nouns work just as well as people in such constructions.